# XSLT Help on choosing latest Operation Node from XML

Tags: xslt

Please find below in more detail. Sorry I am new to this website and to XSLT

I am trying to achieve the below scenario

I have an XML with the below content for an employee

```
<Identifier>
<Operation>ADD</Operation>
<Position_ID>12345</Operation_ID>
<Issued_Date>2013-12-10</Issued_Date>
<Country>CN</Country>
</Identifier>
<Identifier>
<Operation>REMOVE</Operation>
<Position_ID>6734</Operation_ID>
<Issued_Date>2013-11-09</Issued_Date>
<Country>CN</Country>
</Identifier>
```

I am trying to output a txt file with one Operation element from Identifier section as below based on the Recent Operation activity Assuming REMOVE operation is the recent operation, I would like to output as

E001,SAM,PAUL,REMOVE,6734,2013-11-09,CN

If ADD operation is the recent activity happened then I need to output as below

E001,SAM,PAUL,ADD,12345,2013-12-10,CN

I used the below XSLT code inorder to pull the latest, but since I am using the 'or' operator it is providing me the below output which is Incorrect

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="pi:Identifier[pi:Operation = 'ADD' or pi:Operation = 'REMOVE']">                                
<xsl:for-each select="pi:Identifier">
<Identifiers>
<Operation>
<xsl:value-of select="pi:Operation" />
</Operation>
<Position_ID><xsl:value-of select="pi:Position_ID                        </Position_ID
<Country><xsl:value-of select="pi:Country" />                                                          </Country>
<Issued_Date>
<xsl:value-of select="pi:Issued_Date" />
</Issued_Date>
</Identifiers>
</xsl:for-each></xsl:when>
</choose>
```

E001,SAM,PAUL,ADD,12345,2013-12-10,CN,REMOVE,6734,2013-11-09,CN

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Your question is not clear. What is "the latest Operation"? I don't see a date or a time property. -- In addition,  your XMLis not well-formed: `<Position ID>` is not a valid tag, and you have no root element.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your quick reply. I could not put the complete code.This was part of the code which I wanted to display the elements of Identifier section from either ADD operation or REMOVE operation tags.  <Identifier>
<Operation> ADD </Operation>
<Position_ID> 20003432 </Position_ID>
</Identifier>
<Identifier>
<Operation> REMOVE </Operation>
<Position_ID> 20003412 </Position_ID>
</Identifier>

Comment: Welcome to SE - you need to edit your post. Try to be as clear as possible and provide an example that makes sense.

Comment: I am using the below XSLT to get the latest elements based on the operation tag. <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="pi:Identifier"><xsl:for-each select="pi:Identifier[pi:Operation = 'ADD' or pi:Operation = 'MODIFY' or pi:Operation ='REMOVE' or pi:Operation = 'NONE']"><National_Identifiers xtt:separator=","><Operation><xsl:value-of select="pi:Operation" /></Operation></National_Identifiers></xsl:for-each></xsl:when></choose>

Comment: You need to EDIT THE POST, not add a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to output a txt file with one Operation element from
>   Identifier section as below based on the Recent Operation activity

Assuming you are using XSLT 1.0, the way to achieve this is to sort the `Identifier` elements by date, and take the data from the first (or from the last, depending on the sort order) element.

For example, given a **well-formed (!)** input:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <Identifier>
        <Operation>ADD</Operation>
        <Position_ID>12345</Position_ID>
        <Issued_Date>2013-12-10</Issued_Date>
        <Country>CN</Country>
    </Identifier>
    <Identifier>
        <Operation>REMOVE</Operation>
        <Position_ID>6734</Position_ID>
        <Issued_Date>2013-11-09</Issued_Date>
        <Country>CN</Country>
    </Identifier>
</root>
```

applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="Identifier">
        <xsl:sort select="Issued_Date" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:value-of select="Operation" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Position_ID" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Issued_Date" />
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="Country" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will **result** in:

```
ADD,12345,2013-12-10,CN
```